# Java networking code executing before object received

Tags: java, sockets, networking, nullpointerexception, objectinputstream

I have a Java game that uses networking, and I have a client (using a Socket) fetching objects from an ObjectInputStream, running in its own thread.

From [Client.java](https://github.com/lgp/LGP-Multiplayer-Network-Game-Framework/blob/HEAD/GameFramework/src/com/lgposse/net/client/Client.java):

```
        Object input = null;
        while(true) {
            input = in.readObject();
            if(input != null) {
                listener.gotObject(input);
            }
        }
```

This works pretty well. The object is gotten and is passed to the listener, which is a class linked to a my main GameApp class.

From the listener ([NetControl.java](https://github.com/lgp/LGP-Multiplayer-Network-Game-Framework/blob/HEAD/GameFramework/src/com/lgposse/game/net/NetControl.java)):

```
public void gotObject(Object o) {
    System.out.println(o);
    app.gotObject(o);
}
```

"app" is the instance that handles all new objects received and deals with them.

From the app ([GameApp.java](https://github.com/lgp/LGP-Multiplayer-Network-Game-Framework/blob/HEAD/GameFramework/src/com/lgposse/game/app/GameApp.java)) (**edit: the non-abstract [CardGameApp.java](https://github.com/lgp/LGP-Multiplayer-Network-Game-Framework/blob/HEAD/JCards/src/com/lgposse/cards/app/CardGameApp.java) gives greater context**):

```
public void gotObject(Object o) {
    // select instance:
    if(o instanceof GameList) {
        GameList gameList = (GameList) o;
        System.out.println("gamelist: " + gameList);
        this.lobbyControl.gotGameList(gameList);
    }
}
```

I've run this code in the debugger, one step at a time, and it works perfectly. When I run it normally though, I get a null pointer (output is as follows:)

```
Game ID: 0. Name: game1. Players: 1 / 1. // the object, as it is printed in Client.java

gamelist: Game ID: 0. Name: game1. Players: 1 / 1. // the object, as it is printed again in GameApp.java

Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.lgposse.game.app.GameApp.gotObject(GameApp.java:61)
at com.lgposse.game.net.NetControl.gotObject(NetControl.java:47)
at com.lgposse.net.client.Client.run(Client.java:49)
```

Now, I see the object being printed twice, so I know it has been received... but I get a null pointer.

I added a sleep function in the middle of the function:

```
    else if(o instanceof GameList) {
        GameList gameList = (GameList) o;
        System.out.println("gamelist: " + gameList);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000); // sleep 100 still gave null pointer
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        this.lobbyControl.gotGameList(gameList);
    }
```

And setting it to sleep for a while, it all finally worked.

Any idea why I need to sleep the thread like this? Is there something I should do differently? I'm not sure why I was able to print the object while it was still considered null.

Edit: added some more context.

Comment: More information: I asked a friend about this and he mentioned blocking, e.g. waiting for something to be ready first. I'm not familiar with the concept, but I'm guessing what I may want to do is wait until my object is fully received (pseudocode: Thread.sleep(UNTIL OBJECT FULLY RECEIVED); but I'm not sure how that would be done (or how to check when it is done.)

Comment: When i need to wait for a thread(or several) i use a CountDownLatch to synchronize.

Comment: Why are you testing for null? Are you planning on sending nulls?

Comment: @EJP the code originally read while(in.readObject() != null) but I changed it to what you see because that didn't work... I see now that that may be unnecessary in a while(true) loop. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: @ZachHall But why did you ever test for null? You won't get null unless you send null. Maybe you think it's an EOS test, but it isn't. `EOFException` tells you that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `lobbyControl` is `null`, not `gameList`. If `gameList` were null, the top of the stack would be the `gotGameList()` method, not `gotObject()`.

If sleeping helps the problem, then you must be manipulating the `lobbyControl` member without proper concurrency safeguards. An `ObjectInputStream` won't return an object until it's been fully read from the stream, so your problem has nothing to do with not having completely read the object.

---

*Update:* I can't follow all the code, but it appears that a reference to the object being constructed is leaked to a thread (the `client` in the `NetControl`), which is started before the constructor completes. If that is the case, that's *very, very bad.* You should *never* allow a partially constructed object to become visible to another thread.

Comment: Interesting point! I think I realize now I didn't give the full story with my code, as LobbyControl is the one requesting the object from the server. https://github.com/lgp/LGP-Multiplayer-Network-Game-Framework/blob/HEAD/JCards/src/com/lgposse/cards/app/CardGameApp.java - here is the non-abstract class I've been dealing with (forgot about this) that creates a new LobbyControl, which then in its constructor method requests a new game list. (Perhaps it is considered null because the request goes through before the constructor is done?)

Comment: Hm, I've checked again, adding a System.out.println(LobbyControl); and I got null. You're definitely on to something. I'm going to try moving the request so that it is only called when the class is fully formed. I'll post back with results when done.

Comment: Thanks for the insight! I moved the request so that it now reads "new LobbyControl(this); lobbyControl.sendRequest();" instead of having sendRequest anywhere in the constructor, and it works!

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'll start off by saying that the code snippets posted seem to help illustrate the issue, but i don't think the full picture is painted.  I'd ask for a bit more code, to help get a full context.

That being said, I'd offer the following guidance:

1. Don't lean on java's built in object serialization.  It's nice and
   easy to use, but can be very unstable and error prone at runtime. 
   I'd suggest a custom object serialization and deserialization
   scheme.
2. Depending on the scope of the game you're making, NIO may be a
   netter choice.  If you stick with regular IO, then make sure you
   have a rock solid Thread Manager in place to properly handle the
   threads dealing with the socket IO.

..without more code, that's the most I can offer.

Comment: Java Serialization is extremely mature and robust. There's nothing unstable or error prone about it. Especially relative to a roll-your-own serialization protocol.

Comment: We've actually ran into multiple problems dealing with restoring binary data stored in older formats of the same named class.  Additionally, if a class is serialized when it exists in package A, then a refactor down the road causes this class to move to package B, then deserialization of said object will fail every time.

A 'roll your own' protocol can easily harness the power of the Factory and Command patterns and allow you to completely avoid the performance hits from using java's Introspection features.  Also, it allows for, in my experience, better thread safety and much better robustness

Comment: Thanks for the reply! All my code is available online if you'd like the full story. https://github.com/lgp/LGP-Multiplayer-Network-Game-Framework/blob/HEAD/GameFramework/src/com/lgposse/game/app/GameApp.java - Here's the GameApp, https://github.com/lgp/LGP-Multiplayer-Network-Game-Framework/tree/HEAD/GameFramework/src/com/lgposse/game/net shows NetControl and some others. (Can't include more than 2 links yet I think, but the rest can be found in com.lgposse.net. (I have too many packages, I know).

Comment: Again, this is all 'In my experience' as is much with Java.  Many ways to skin the serialization cat.  I prefer to not use the built in java object serialization mechanisms for the above said reasons.  I'll take a look at your code zshall and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

Just to improve my comment...When i need to wait for one or more threads to finish, i like to use java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch. Its very simple:

```
//game class
public class DummyGame
{
    CountDownLatch signal;

    public DummyGame( CountDownLatch signal)
    {
        this.signal = signal;
    }
   public void run()
   {
      doLogic();
      signal.countDown();
   }
}

//game controller class

 public void run()
 { 
    while (! gameOver)
    {
       CountDownLatch signal = new CountDownLatch(1); //wait one thread to finish
       new thread(newGame(signal)).start();

       //wait for game run() to finish
        signal.await();

       updateInterface();
    }
 }
```

That's just an idea, hope it helps.